# WebApi not finding action on controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Good afternoon.
I've created an ajax call that is trying to reach my C# function, however; i get the error "No action was found on the controller 'PortalApi' that matches the request.'  The request is a post and the server function has the appropriate Http header attached to it.  The function name and parameters are all identical as well.

Ajax

```
GetExtendersGridDataFromServer(requestParameters) {
    extendersGridSource = null;
    var gridFilterParams = JSON.stringify(requestParameters);
    $.ajax(
    {
        async: false, 
        contentType: "application/json",
        converters: Utills.jQueryAjaxJsondDataConverter,
        data: JSON.stringify({ gridFilterParams: gridFilterParams, securityCode: securityCode }),
        dataType: "jsond",
        type: "POST",
        url: (Utills.getBaseURL() + "/Api/PortalApi/GetExtenderGridData"),
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert("failure");
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JqGridData GetExtenderGridData(string securityCode)
    {
        IMUserSecurity.UserSecurity.ValidateWebMethodSecurityCode(securityCode, "PortalWebService.GetExtenderGridData");

        return GetDoctorGridData("extender");
    }
```

route config

```
    configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Action Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new
        {
            id = RouteParameter.Optional
        });
```

Comment: What is the name of the controller class?

Comment: In route config, add a '?' after `id`. like   `"configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Action Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}","` .  Otherwise an id value is required in the url to match this route config

Comment: @Clint PortalApiController

Comment: check your browsers debug tab.  Modern browsers will check for cross site origin policies by sending an HTTP-OPTION request before sending HTTP-POST.  Based off your code, the options endpoint is not found thus failing.  You can Add [HttpOption] tag to the endpoint or remove the [HTTPPost] all together to test that.  When writing WebAPIs in .net you need to pay very close attention to how browsers treat cross site origin policies.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the FromBody attribute ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)).

```
public JqGridData GetExtenderGridData([FromBody] Security security) { ... }


public class Security
{
    public object GridFilterParams { get; set; }
    public string SecurityCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It hits the GetExtenderGridData function, however; the security seems to get lost.

Comment: I updated my reply. Try updating it to the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible problems here:

**Routing**

I recommend you to use attribute routing instead of being depending on the convention routing(*IMO it can be pain*)

Enable attribute routing in the `Register` method in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then decore your api controller and api method with the `RoutePrefix` and `Route` attributes. Together the `RoutePrefix` + `Route` combine to build your complete route to your method, in this
example `api/PortalApi/GetExtenderGridData`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PortalApi")]
public class PortalApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetExtenderGridData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Order> FindOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
}
```

**Request Body**

Your api method `FindOrdersByCustomer` takes one string as parameter but your client are trying to send an object to the method which is not possible at the moment.
The client object is defined as

```
{ gridFilterParams: gridFilterParams, securityCode: securityCode }
```

To be able to send that to the backend api, you need to make sure it matches that signature.
Create a class which relects the client model (I don't know what the `gridFilterParams` are but you get the point here)

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public object GridFilterParams { get;set; }
    public string SecurityCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then read that from the request body in the api method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PortalApi")]
public class PortalApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetExtenderGridData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Order> FindOrdersByCustomer([FromBody]RequestModel model) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was good too, his just came first. Thanks for all your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't enough reputation to comment but you can try this

```
[HttpPost("GetExtenderGridData")
```

instead of

```
[HttpPost].
```

Comment: HttpPostAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments